# Following sibling doesn't work on google search

Tags: xpath

I am trying to write my own Xpath using following sibling concept on Google Search page and trying to select "Google Search" button on that but when I check my Xpath in Firefox console it isn't able to identify the element.

I tried by removing following sibling tag and it worked but it doesn't work when I use following-sibling tag.

**This works** -

```
$x("//div[@id='searchform']/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/center/input[1]")
```

This is what I am using in console.

**This doesn't work** -

```
$x("//div[@id='searchform']/form/div[2]/div/following-sibling::div[2]/center/input[1]")
```

I am expecting it to highlight "Google Search" button but it isn't recognizing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"x/following-sibling::y" looks for a sibling of type "y" of type "x" element.**

`/div/div[3]/center` looks for third `div` child of first `div` element,

but `/div/following-sibling::div[2]/center` looks for second `div` sibling of first `div` element and not child of it as in first case, which fails.

So in your case,

```
$x("//div[@id='searchform']/form/div[2]/div/div/following-sibling::div[2]/center/input[1]")
```

should work for you.